# How to Display data from a UIDatePicker into a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uidatepicker

I would like to get the date from a UIDatePicker and add it to a UITableView cell.
[image]

I have tried to put a label into a Table View Cell and update each time the person using the app clicks add date. However, it is the un-logical way to do it, and Xcode does not let me do it by giving me errors.

I have therefore put a label outside the tableview to just test and whenever I click on the Add Date button, the date gets displayed.

Here is my code from the view controller folder

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var examDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet weak var AddClassButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var datesTable: UITableViewCell!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    AddClassButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: examDatePicker.date)


    dateLabel.text = selectedDate

  //  datesTable

    //myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        }



  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement data source method of table view and after select date from datepicker you need to reload tableview and assign that selected date to cell's label

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var selectedDate : String ? //Make global variable 

 func pressButton(button: UIButton) {
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
     selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: examDatePicker.date)
     self.IBtableView.reload()
 }


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
      return 1 //anything you want
 }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? YourCustomCell // Or UITableViewCell
   cell. dateLabel.text = selectedDate ?? "SelectDateFromDatePicker"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This answer varies slightly from the one provided by Sunil Prajapati, demonstrating using an array to hold the strings, which is I think is a more standard pattern.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    // MARK: - Properties
    var tableSource = [String]()

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func pickDateButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        // a bit contrived, but you get the idea
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        // get the date
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        // put the string in the data source for the table
        tableSource.insert(dateString, at: 0)
        table.reloadData()
        // profit? 
    }


    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableSource[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it and it worked. I am grateful